# Apply formatting to the WHOLE row/column if ANY of the cells fulfils condition

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Conditional formatting, even when applied to the whole row/column, treats each cell individually and applies formatting only to the cells that meet criteria.

**Example:**
An attempt to highlight whole row 7 if any of the cells is not blank:

[image]

Result: As mentioned above, highlights only specific cells, not the whole row.

If only there was a *range-aware* version of the `isblank()` function, that would operate on a range of cells instead of treating each cell individually. Like so: `=not(isblank(row(A7:7)))` - This works not as desired, i.e. it evaluates `row(A7:7)` as an integer literal `7`, and, since `7` is not blank, the whole expression evaluates to `TRUE`, regardless of the contents of the cells.

Is it possible to achieve this *range-aware* formatting on formula level, i.e. without a custom script?

*(Yeah, yeah, I'm aware that a custom script for that is not that time-consuming to write, but more people might be facing the same problem, so a more user-friendly solution is welcome.)*

---

### Update 6/14/2018:

Formatting in google sheets seems to be buggy and/or poor-documented. That might be the reason why  @Ceu Melo's solution works for me even with numbers, despite @Rubén claiming otherwise:

[image]

#### Bugginess demonstration:

An attempt to highlight whole row if a condition holds true for a specific cell (B2) in that row:

[image]

No better if B2 is changed to C2 in the condition:

[image]

On a real-world document it looks equally terrible:

[image]

Changing data format didn't seem to affect formatting behaviour at all.
In the screenshots it's set to "Automatic".

Comment: Don't enclose integer literal between quotes as Google Sheets and other spreadsheets handle them as text.

Comment: @Rubén fixed. Is it ok now?

Comment: If found the edit made today confusing, after the hr it says that one answer works for you but that answer was not currently the accepted answer, later the edit include a "bugginess demonstration", but it's not refers previously referred answer. What is the point of that demonstration in the context of a Q&A thread?

Comment: I wanted to see your response before accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the function COUNTA, it counts the number of cells in a range that are not empty,

and indicate more than zero for conditional rule:

[image]

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: That will not work for cells having numbers

Comment: @Rubén Take a look at "Update 6/14/2018" section in the question.

Comment: When I posted my comment COUNTA didn't work for cells having numbers but today it works.

Answer (score 3):

For area A1:E500 using a custom forumula:

`=if($B1="Purchased",1)`

Will highlight the entire row if `Purchased` is in the B column.  The key point is locking the check to the B column with the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to achieve this range-aware formatting on formula level, i.e. without a custom script?

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible.

## Instructions

For the "Apply to range" setting use

```
7:7
```

Considering that

- 0 values are parsed as FALSE
- Other numbers are parsed as TRUE

for the "Custom formula" setting use

```
=COUNT(7:7)+COUNTA(7:7)
```

- COUNT counts cells having numbers
- COUNTA counts cells having texts, even `""`

Or

```
=COLUMNS(7:7)-COUNTBLANK(7:7)
```

- COLUMNS return the number of columns
- COUNTBLANK return the number of blanks

---

## NOTES

### June 14, 2018

After a comment from the OP and reading today's question update, I tested the [solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114934/88163) proposed by Ceu Melo and today it worked for numbers too, despite that COUNTA is supposed to count only cells that have text, not numbers.

Answer (score -1):

`=counta(7:7)>0`

Worked for me in conditional formatting for a range of 30 rows x 3 columns.